# Extract and import text of PDF file

Tags: pdf, import, export, language-translation

I need to translate several PDF files (image heavy) the thing is that there is a lot of text there, i'm looking for a way to extract it from text boxes to a text file for translation  and import it back to the same text boxes.

There is a program that can do something similar called Infix, however I have no ability to unite text boxes and as a result i get messed up text.

Comment: It is fully editable text i'm talking about there is no need in software to recognize it, such as finereader etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "PDF-XChange Pro 5". This is a program (ca. 70 Euro). By means of it you can then separate the text and images from a PDF-document, and save that in a e.g. text-file.
I hope this helps.

Comment: I've tried it, you can't get text back to the same text boxes